# Get the next x months from today's date

Tags: javascript

I have tried using Moment.js to achieve this, but I cannot think of the best way.

So far I have added 3 months from today's date, like so:

```
moment().add(3, 'months');
```

But from here I am stuck on what to try and couldn't find any other questions for this particular scenario.

Preferably, I would like an array like this returned:

```
// based on today's date (28/11/2016)
['December 2016', 'January 2017', 'February 2017']
```

Comment: what about a loop?

Comment: `[1, 2, 3].map(i => moment().add(i, 'months').format('MMMM YYYY'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be straight forward with a loop

```js
var arr = [];

for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  arr.push(moment().add(i, 'months').format("MMMM YYYY"))
}

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```